# Excel Formula with VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel spreadsheet with two sheets.

On one sheet, labeled WorshipLeaders, I have the following in columns A & B

Col A  Col B
Jimmy  500
Johnny 300
Billy  200

I'm trying to get the second sheet (called Schedule) to populate a column with the number from WorshipLeaders Col B when I select the name from the drop down list. I've got the list part figured out, but I can't quite dial in the VLOOKUP.

Here's the formula I'm using that is almost working, but it grabs the wrong number:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B6)),VLOOKUP(Schedule!B6,WorshipLeaders!A:B,2),"")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this`=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B6)),VLOOKUP(Schedule!B6,WorshipLeaders!A:B,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: That did it. Thank you. What does the FALSE do?